# Magento admin users - multiple users for employees?

Tags: admin

Currently there are working 4 employees on our magento shop, they are mainly creating new products.

Is it neccessary to create a unique user for every employee or is it ok to use just one admin user for every employee?

The core of the question is: is it harmful to the shops performance if different employees use one account? Or are there any other problems that could occur?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same user for multiple employees, but I wouldn't recommend that. 
What if someone gets fired?
If they all use the same account you have to change passwords everywhere.
If each one has a separate account you can just deactivate it.

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest adding multiple users as Marius said.  Additionally as company grows you may want to assign different roles for different users.

Our company went through the same process you are suggesting.  We had just one user that was shared, but later became problematic.